# CSS overlay effect doesent work on diferent resolution monitors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, hover

This probably isn't the best description of my problem but I tried to keep it short and also somehow describe the problem I'm having...

In advance I would like to apologize for my bad english, it's not my native language so if there are some unclarities about what the problem is please just comment bellow :)

So here it goes... I built eight tiles **(using Bootstrap 4 beta 3)** that when hovered an overlay animation happens and the image is overlayed by some new content... And it all works fine on my computer screen (resolution is 1920x1080) but the problem with the overlay happens when the page is viewed on a monitor of higer or smaller resolution. The overlay goes higher than it should or it doesent go high enough to cover the entire image.
Perhaps my SCSS isn't structured corectly? Or i'm targeting the hover incorectly? I tried to figure it out on my own but this is the only way that my animation even happens

This is the best way I know how to describe it in english... So ia recreated it in a CodePen and you guys can see the problem there just try resizing your window and hoverin images and you will know what I mean :)

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/Weindorfer/pen/YYRjWN)

But just in case I'm also posting code here:
**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
<div class="container-fluid tiles">
        <div class="row no-gutters prva">
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="reklamni-napisi">
                    <a href="reklamne_table.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>reklamne <br /> <b>table</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">Reklamne table & 3D črke</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/reklamni-napisi.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>Različne <b>izvedbe, materiali</b> in <b>velikosti.</b></p>
                                <p>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2D in 3D črke<br />
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> LED reklamne table in
                                    kasete<br />
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> neosvetljene reklamne table<br />
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> reklamni panoji<br />
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> vrtljive reklamne
                                    table<br />
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> aluminijaste table in
                                    sistem napetega platna
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gumba">
                                <a href="#">CLASSIC <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#">PRO <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="reklamni-stebri">
                    <a href="reklamni_stebri.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>reklamni <br /> <b>stebri</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">Piloni/totemi</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/reklamni-stebri.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    <b>Reklamni stebri,</b> reklamni <b>totemi</b> in osvetljeni <b>piloni</b>.
                                    <br />
                                    Iz različnih materialov, napogosteje pleksi stekla in aluminija. Notranja LED
                                    razsvetljava ali zunanja
                                    osvetlitev z reflektorji.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gumba">
                                <a href="#">CLASSIC <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#">PRO <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="neonski-napisi">
                    <a href="neonski_napisi.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>neonski<br /><b>napisi</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">Črke in dekoracije</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/neonski-napisi.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    <b>Neonski svetlobni napisi</b> se izdelujejo ročno iz krivljenih barvnih
                                    steklenih cevi premera 10 do 24
                                    mm, ki jih s segrevanjem lahko oblikujemo v različne oblike kot je srček, oblak
                                    ali
                                    <b>obliko po vaši želji.</b>
                                    Retro je moderno.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="vizualna-oprema">
                    <a href="vizualna_oprema.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>vizualna <br /> oprema</h2>
                        <p class="opis">Bencinskih servisov</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/vizualna-oprema-beninskih-servisov.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    Z <b>lastno proizvodnjo,</b> vrhunsko strojno tehnologijo in skupino visoko
                                    usposobljenih sodelavcev, izdelamo
                                    in opremimo bencinske servise z <b>vizualnimi reklamnimi elementi.</b>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters druga">
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="alu-drogovi">
                    <a href="aluminijasti_drogovi.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>aluminijasti<br /><b>drogovi</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">Za zastave</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/aluminijasti-drogovi-za-zastave.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    <b>Aluminijasti drogovi za zastave</b> višine 6, 8, 10 ali 12 m v eloksirani ali
                                    beli barvi, s 360° vrtljivo prečko
                                    in <b>enostavnim sistemom za zamenjavo zastav,</b> ter vključenim sidrom za
                                    postavitev zastave.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gumba">
                                <a href="#">CLASSIC <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#">PRO <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="reklamne-tablice">
                    <a href="reklamne-tablice.php"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>reklamne<br /><b>tablice</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">Notranji označevalni sistemi</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/reklamne-tablice.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    <b>Individualno izdelane usmerjevalne table,</b> pisarniške tablice, tablice z
                                    napisi, reklamne tablice in info
                                    točke. Prikubljeni tekstilni panoji z alu okvirjem in potiskanim platnom.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gumba">
                                <a href="#">CLASSIC <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a href="#">PRO <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="pleksi-steklo">
                    <a href="#"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2><b>pleksi</b><br />steklo</h2>
                        <p class="opis">Oblikovanje in predelava</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/pleksi-steklo.jpg" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    Oblikovanje in predelava <b>akrilnega stekla</b> po meri zajema izdelke za
                                    namene reklamne industrije, pisarniškega
                                    inventarja, opreme gostinskih lokalov, sejemskih prostrov, lekarn, trgovin ter
                                    unikatne udelke.
                                    Praktično <b>neomejene možnosti uporabe.</b>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="web-shop">
                    <a href="https://shop.neonart.si/"><div class="naslov">
                        <h2>spletna<br /><b>trgovina</b></h2>
                        <p class="opis">shop.neonart.si</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="slika">
                        <img src="http://neonart.oblikovanje.mobi/public/assets/images/spletna-trgovina.png" alt="slika" class="img-fluid">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>
                                    Prospektna stojala, namizna in zidna držala za brošure, klip klap okvirji za
                                    plakate, oglasne deske, vitrine, pingvini, roll up stojala, A-table za plakate
                                    in cenovno ugodni klasični izdelki iz PVC.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
#main {
position     : relative;
background   : #ededed;
  background-position : center;
  background-repeat   : no-repeat;
  background-size     : cover;
  .container {
    padding-top : 160px;
    .unique-heading {
      padding-bottom : 130px;
      .big-heading {
        color       : #ffffff;
        //font-size   : 5rem;
        font-weight : 300;
        .pink {
          color       : #ed145b;
          font-weight : 900;
        }
        .material-pink {
          color : #f59298;
        }
      }
      .line {
        margin           : 0 auto;
        background-color : #c7bfc2;
        content          : '';
        display          : block;
        width            : 80px;
        height           : 2px;
        transition       : all .4s cubic-bezier(.73, .14, .14, .78);
      }
      .sub-heading {
        text-transform : uppercase;
        color          : #ededed;
        letter-spacing : 12px;
        font-size      : 1.4rem;
        font-weight    : 100;
      }
    }
  }
  .tiles {
    padding-bottom : 170px;
    .prva, .druga {
      padding-bottom : 10px;
      .reklamni-napisi {
        background-color : #ed145b;
        position         : relative;
      }
      .reklamni-stebri {
        background-color : #00a99d;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #00a99d !important;
        }
      }
      .neonski-napisi {
        background-color : #f177ae;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #f177ae !important;
        }
      }
      .vizualna-oprema {
        background-color : #ed1c26;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #ed1c26 !important;
        }
      }
    .alu-drogovi {
        background-color : #7670b3;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #7670b3 !important;
        }
      }
      .reklamne-tablice {
        background-color : #f7941f;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #f7941f !important;
        }
      }
      .pleksi-steklo {
        background-color : #659ad2;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #659ad2 !important;
        }
      }
      .web-shop {
        background-color : #92278c;
        position         : relative;
        .overlay {
          background-color : #92278c !important;
        }
      }
      a {
        color           : #ffffff;
        text-decoration : none;
        .naslov {
          color        : #ffffff;
          font-weight  : 300;
          padding-left : 22px;
          padding-top  : 25px;
          h2 {
            font-size      : 1.6rem;
            text-transform : uppercase;
            font-weight    : 100;
          }
          .opis {
            font-size : 0.8rem;
          }
        }
      }
      .slika {
        &:hover {
          .overlay {
            height : 69%;
          }
        }
        img {
          display : block;
          width   : 100%;
          height  : auto;
        }
        .overlay {
          position         : absolute;
          bottom           : 0;
          left             : 0;
          background-color : #ed145b;
          overflow         : hidden;
          width            : 100%;
          height           : 0;
          transition       : .5s ease;
          .text {
            padding-bottom : 10px;
            padding-left   : 22px;
            padding-right  : 22px;
            color          : white;
            font-size      : 0.8rem;
            font-weight    : 400;
            overflow       : hidden;
          }
          .gumba {
            padding-left : 22px;
            a {
              color           : #ffffff;
              text-decoration : none;
              font-size       : 0.9rem;
              font-weight     : 400;
              height          : 48px;
              border          : 1px solid white;
              text-align      : center;
              padding         : 15px 32px 15px 32px;
        }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Blacksilver it' minimized as best as I know how to and I also included now a working codepen :) But if I knew hot to minimize it better I would have done it :)

Comment: The height of the overlay is set to 69%, but the height of the the title (`.naslov`) is constant, and the contents of the overlay are variable. You should probably use some JS to calculate the heights and equalize them.

(PS: The title is only constant by luck: the amount of text is close enough that you haven't run to another line, but they could be as variable as the overlays.)